# django form no errors

Tags: python, django, forms, django-forms

I am trying to create a custom login form, when I validate the form there are no errors and it is not valid

Is there a better way to implement what I want? At least I want just to get the values from the form fields.

```
class LoginForm(AuthenticationForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(LoginForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    username = forms.CharField()
    password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput(
        attrs={
            'class': 'form-control',
            'placeholder': '',
        }
    ))

def login(request):

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = LoginForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            print(True)
        else:
            print(False)

        print(username)
        print(password)
        # authUrl = ""
        # authData = {'usname': request.POST['username'],
        #             'psword': request.POST['password'],
        #            }
        # s = requests.Session()
        # rAuth = s.post(authUrl, data=authData).json()

        # if rAuth["status"] == 200:
        #     pass
    else:
        form = LoginForm()

    return render(request, 'users/login.html', {'form': form})
```

Comment: Don't subclass Django's AuthenticationForm if you're not using it to authenticate to Django's authentication system.

Comment: If you are using bootstrap - I would recommend looking into [crispy-forms](https://django-crispy-forms.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I normally use my own form like this

forms

```
class LoginForm(forms.Form):
    email = forms.EmailField(label="Email")
    password = forms.CharField(label="Password", widget=forms.PasswordInput())

    def clean(self, *args, **kwargs):
        email = self.cleaned_data.get("email")
        password = self.cleaned_data.get("password")
        user = authenticate(username=email, password=password)
        if not user: 
            raise forms.ValidationError("Failed to authenticate this user")
        if not user.check_password(password):
            raise forms.ValidationError("Incorrect password")
        if not user.is_active:
            raise forms.ValidationError("This user has been deactivated")
        return super(LoginForm, self).clean(*args, **kwargs)
```

view

```
class LoginView(View):
    def get(self, request):
        context = {
            'form': LoginForm()
        }
        return render(request, "www/login.html", context)

    def post(self, request):
        form = LoginForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            user = authenticate(username=request.POST.get("email"), password=request.POST.get("password"))
            login(request, user)
            return redirect('index')
        context = {'form': form}
        return render(request, "www/login.html", context)
```

Hopefully this is some benefit to you